# How to access arraylist outside the oncreate

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hi i am new to programming. I want access arraylist outside from the onCreate but i get error.Below is code.

```
public class WelcomeOnFootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_on_foot);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtra;
        List<UserDate> data= new ArrayList();
        data.add((UserData)bundle.get("data"));
        next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handle();
            }
        });
    }
private void handle(){
      String info=data.getUserInfo;// here i get error
}
}
```

Comment: You have to declare just this List Out side of the onCreate() method

Comment: Do you know about `private`, `protected`, `public` or **Scope of Variables**?

Comment: sorry i am new to programming. arpit patel thanks its accessable now

Comment: no problem if my answer is work for you then accept it. also you can Appreciate with upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WelcomeOnFootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton next;
 List<UserDate> data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_on_foot);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtra;
         data= new ArrayList();
        data.add((UserData)bundle.get("data"));
        next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handle();
            }
        });
    }
private void handle(){
      String info=data.getUserInfo;// here i get error
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the list globally at class level. In your case before OnCreate.

```
List<UserDate> data= new ArrayList();
en@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_on_foot);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtra;
    data.add((UserData)bundle.get("data"));
    next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handle();
        }
    });


   }
  private void handle(){
      String info=data.getUserInfo;
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WelcomeOnFootActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    ImageButton next;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_on_foot);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtra;
       final List<UserDate> data= new ArrayList();
        data.add((UserData)bundle.get("data"));
        next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                handle(data); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
private void handle(List<UserDate> listUD){ 
      String info=listUD.getUserInfo;// here i get error
} 
}
```